# MySQL index optimization with Subquery vs Left Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have created 2 queries that I can use that do the same function.  They both contain properties that I would like to merge into a single query but I have been unable to.

QUERY 1 
 - Gives me exactly the results I want. Slow (~0.700 sec)

QUERY 2
 - Gives me a lot of rows that I ignore and skip over.  Fast (~0.005 sec)

My goal is to modify QUERY 2 to drop all null price rows except 1 for each item.  I can't seem to do this with out taking a ding on performance.  This is due to my lack of experience and understanding of index use in MySQL.

QUERY 1

Uses a poorly designed subquery which does not allow the use of indexing across tbl_sale (e) which contains 10k rows.

```
SELECT b.id, b.sv, b.description, der.store_id, f.name, der.price
FROM tbl_watch AS a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_item AS b ON a.item_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.store_id, d.flyer_id, e.item_id, e.price
    FROM tbl_storewatch AS c, tbl_storeflyer AS d
    FORCE INDEX ( storebeg_ndx ) , tbl_sale AS e
    WHERE c.user_id = '$user_id'
    AND (
        d.store_id = c.store_id
        AND d.date_beg = '20121206'
        )
    AND e.flyer_id = d.flyer_id
        ) AS der ON a.item_id = der.item_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_store as f ON der.store_id = f.id
WHERE a.user_id = '$user_id'
ORDER BY b.description ASC
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for QUERY 1

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     a           ref     user_item_ndx   user_item_ndx   4           const   30  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     b           eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY         4           a.item_id   1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL    300     
1   PRIMARY     f           eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY         4           der.store_id    1   
2   DERIVED     c           ref     user_ndx        user_ndx        4                   6   
2   DERIVED     e           ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL                9473    Using join buffer
2   DERIVED     d           eq_ref  storebeg_ndx    storebeg_ndx    8           c.store_id  1   Using where
```

QUERY 2

Uses all left joins which is very efficient (with the exception of the ORDER BY).  Indexes are used on every join. This query returns all possible matches for every item in tbl_watch. Here is the query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.sv, b.description, c.store_id, f.name, e.price
FROM tbl_watch AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_item AS b ON a.item_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_storewatch AS c ON c.user_id = '$user_id'
LEFT JOIN tbl_storeflyer AS d ON d.store_id = c.store_id
    AND d.date_beg = '$s_date'
LEFT JOIN tbl_sale AS e ON e.item_id = a.item_id
    AND e.flyer_id = d.flyer_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_store as f ON d.store_id = f.id
WHERE a.user_id = '$user_id'
ORDER BY b.description ASC
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for the query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys           key             key_len     ref                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          a       ref     user_item_ndx           user_item_ndx   4           const                   6       Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          b       eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY         4           a.item_id               1   
1   SIMPLE          c       ref     user_ndx                user_ndx        4           const                   2   
1   SIMPLE          d       eq_ref  storebeg_ndx,storendx   storebeg_ndx    8           c.store_id,const        1   
1   SIMPLE          e       eq_ref  itemflyer_ndx           itemflyer_ndx   8           a.item_id,d.flyer_id    1   
1   SIMPLE          f       eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY         4           d.store_id              1
```

How can I modify QUERY 2 (more efficient) to give me just the rows I need like in QUERY 1 to work with?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: I'm not really sure how it's possible that the first query gives you what you want. A left join isn't a left outer join (though perhaps it is in MySQL, it being non-SQL compliant), and nulls aren't unique values. I don't have MySQL handy, but dropping this into PostgreSQL doesn't give the results you describe.  My answer below...

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will give you what you want:

```
select a.id, a.sv, a.description, c.id, c.name, b.price
  from 
    tbl_item a left outer join tbl_sale b on (a.id=b.item_id)
      left outer join tbl_storeflyer d on (b.flyer_id=d.flyer_id and d.date_beg = '20120801')
      left outer join tbl_store c on (d.store_id = c.id)
      left outer join tbl_storewatch x on (c.id = x.store_id)
      left outer join tbl_watch y on (a.id = y.item_id);
```

with NULLs involved, you're likely going to have some left joins.  The alternate way is to use a union, which with MySQL may be faster:

```
 select a.id, a.sv, a.description, c.id as store_id, c.name, b.price
  from
    tbl_item a,
    tbl_sale b,
    tbl_storeflyer d,
    tbl_store c,
    tbl_storewatch x,
    tbl_watch y
  where
    a.id = b.item_id and
    b.flyer_id = d.flyer_id and
    d.store_id = c.id and
    c.id = x.store_id and
    a.id = y.item_id and
    d.date_beg = '20120801'
union
 select a.id, a.sv, a.description, null as store_id, null as name, null as price
  from
    tbl_item a
  where
    a.id not in (select b.item_id from tbl_sale b);
```

you might play with the second half of the union being a left outer join instead of a 'not in' subquery - depends on how your version of MySQL optimizes.

Answer (score 0):

Your subselect in QUERY 1 is using implicit inner joins, while query 2 is using all left joins explicit joins.  Thus, there are no where clauses to exclude data in query 2.    I'd take out the LEFT's in a couple of lines (as marked) and see how this improves things:

```
SELECT b.id, b.sv, b.description, c.store_id, f.name, e.price
FROM tbl_watch AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_item AS b ON a.item_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_storewatch AS c ON c.user_id = '$user_id'
-- Left removed below
JOIN tbl_storeflyer AS d ON d.store_id = c.store_id
    AND d.date_beg = '$s_date'
-- Left removed below
JOIN tbl_sale AS e ON e.item_id = a.item_id
    AND e.flyer_id = d.flyer_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_store as f ON d.store_id = f.id
WHERE a.user_id = '$user_id'
ORDER BY b.description ASC`
```

You also might consider taking the and clauses out of the joins and moving them to the WHERE:

```
SELECT b.id, b.sv, b.description, c.store_id, f.name, e.price
FROM tbl_watch AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_item AS b ON a.item_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_storewatch AS c ON c.user_id = '$user_id'
JOIN tbl_storeflyer AS d ON d.store_id = c.store_id
JOIN tbl_sale AS e ON e.item_id = a.item_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_store as f ON d.store_id = f.id
WHERE a.user_id = '$user_id'
AND d.date_beg = '$s_date'
AND e.flyer_id = d.flyer_id 
ORDER BY b.description ASC
```

and finally, date math is fairly intensive.  In query 2, using outer joins, you avoid alot of it, but you might need it.  I'd try to use a subquery to get ids and restrict by that:

```
SELECT b.id, b.sv, b.description, c.store_id, f.name, e.price
FROM tbl_watch AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_item AS b ON a.item_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_storewatch AS c ON c.user_id = '$user_id'
JOIN tbl_storeflyer AS d ON d.store_id = c.store_id
JOIN tbl_sale AS e ON e.item_id = a.item_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_store as f ON d.store_id = f.id
WHERE a.user_id = '$user_id'
AND e.flyer_id = d.flyer_id 
AND d.id in  (select d.id from d where date_beg = '$s_date')
ORDER BY b.description ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  These solutions do give rows for all items with active sale items (e.item_id = a.item_id AND e.flyer_id = d.flyer_id) but I also was trying to include each item in tbl_watch (a) with (b) fields even if they do not exist in tbl_sale (e). So I would end up with : id, sv, description, NULL, NULL, NULL. I only wanted to allow 1 row with NULLs per item.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Just to clarify I would expect each item to fall into 1 of 3 scenarios: 1 - Item with single price.  2 - Item with multiple prices.  3 - Item with no prices.  If 3 occurs I still want a row returned with the item id, sv, and description.

Comment: not sure date_beg here is an actual date field, looks like it's being used as a char of some kind.  I'm not sure about date match being slow in MySQL, but I'd be surprised.  Dates are normally stored internally as a long, and the only cost is to covert that string into a long, so I'm not convinced it would add any overhead at all.